# Code is not paralleled when compiling cpp file, but c is paralleled

Tags: c++, c, matlab, openmp, mex

I am running the example from [here](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=1795) which allows Matlab to run C function, inside of which some parallel processing happens (with the support of OpenMP).

Compile:

```
mex mex_sum_openmp.c CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -fopenmp" LDFLAGS="\$LDFLAGS -fopenmp"
```

In Matlab:

```
>> tic;mex_sum_openmp(x);toc 
Elapsed time is 0.186795 seconds.
```

Example runs correctly, but if I rename the file extension to cpp then suddenly code is not paralleled.

Compile:

```
mex mex_sum_openmp.cpp CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -fopenmp" LDFLAGS="\$LDFLAGS -fopenmp"
```

In Matlab:

```
>> tic;mex_sum_openmp(x);toc 
Elapsed time is 0.466988 seconds.
```

This combination of CPP+OpenMP+MEX doesn't work at all or am I missing something?

I run Ubuntu 14.04 with Matlab 2014a and GCC 4.8.4. Mex compiler complains about the not supported version of GCC (it supports GCC 4.7.x), but seem to compile things anyway. Can this be a problem?

Comment: Why do you need to name `c` files with `.cpp` extension?

Comment: CFLAGS are for C, CXXFLAGS are for C++. Note, CPPFLAGS are for something else still. In order to avoid confusion, it is highly recommended to refrain from using the non-word "CPP" when referring to the C++ language.

Comment: Thanks @n.m.! That was indeed a problem of CXXFLAGS. Running mex mex_sum_openmp.cpp CXXFLAGS="\$CXXFLAGS -fopenmp" LDFLAGS="\$LDFLAGS -fopenmp" did paralleled the code!

Comment: If you have solved it by your self please provide the answer how you did it so that other users facing the same problem can profit from it. Do it by your self or wait for n.m. Is going to answer it as he did already in his comment

Comment: Don't write *Solved:* in the question title, if it is solved then write out your own answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: It is very confusing to call C++ as CPP or to use .cpp. The CPP is traditionally a C PreProcessor, the `cpp` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @n.m. pointed out in order to compile a c++ file I have to use CXXFLAGS instead of CFLAGS.

Running

```
mex mex_sum_openmp.cpp CXXFLAGS="\$CXXFLAGS -fopenmp" LDFLAGS="\$LDFLAGS -fopenmp"
```

solved the problem.